# request.getparameter() returns null sometimes

Tags: jsp

```
String value = (String) request.getParameter("value");
```

sometimes return null.

How can I fix this?

I am passing the value like this from page to page.

```
<a href=page2.jsp?value =<%=value %>"> Page2</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have any white space before the = sign in your URL, and you should have a quote before the URL:

```
<a href="page2.jsp?value=<%=value %>">Page2</a>
        ^               ^
```

You should also encode the parameter value, and avoid scriptlets. Use The JSTL:

```
<c:url var="page2Url" value="page2.jsp">
    <c:param name="value" value="${someBean.value}"/>
</c:url>
<a href="${fn:escapeXml(page2Url)}">Page2</a>
```

Read [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Other than that, any user may remove the parameter from the URL in its address bar, so maybe that's the reason for a null parameter.